# Boot loader problem

Tags: dual-boot

After Installation of Ubuntu to my new HDD, I putted my existing Win 7 HDD to my motherboard.

Now when I tried to boot windows by default Ubuntu is opening.

Plz do let me know how to fix the boot loader of Ubuntu?

Comment: what exactly u do firstly install Ubuntu after that win7 or You  have 2 different hdd . explain

Answer (score 2):

You need to define in your BIOS settings that the HDD that you want to boot is your Windows HDD, if you cannot find that option in your BIOS (99.9% will have it) you need to swap the cables between your Ubuntu HDD and your Windows HDD.

There should not be an issue here since you apparently installed Ubuntu and Windows in to 2 different disks: both have different MBR and boot loaders installed.

Either select which disk you want to boot from in your BIOS or swap the cables from one disk to the other.

Comment: In case of 2 different hard disk +1